# Some questions on the grammar of this sentence

Tags: grammar

> Der Bund der Kommunisten, eine internationale Arbeiterverbindung, die unter den damaligen Verhältnissen selbstredend nur eine geheime sein konnte, beauftragte auf dem in London im November 1847 abgehaltenen Kongresse die Unterzeichneten mit der Abfassung eines für die Öffentlichkeit bestimmten, ausführlichen theoretischen und praktischen Parteiprogramms.<sup>(aus dem [Vorwort zum Kommunistischen Manifest](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/manifest-der-kommunistischen-partei-4975/2))</sup>

1. > beauftragte auf dem

   What does *dem* refer to?
2. > beauftragte auf dem in London im November 1847 abgehaltenen Kongresse

   According to the German grammar, I learned, I would use the following word order:

   > beauftragte auf dem abgehaltenen kongress in london im November 1847

   I seldom hear my teacher say something like

   > Ich habe deine gestern an der Uni schöne Töchter gesehen.

   Is such an expression acceptable?
3. I am uncertain about the meaning of:

   > … mit der Abfassung eines für die Öffentlichkeit bestimmten

   and I feel that there must be some words *eines* refers to, but I don’t know what they are.

Comment: Please type with some care.

Comment: Doesn't it say "die Unterzeichnenden"?

Comment: I wondered too, but it doesn't: http://books.google.de/books?id=Mjj0NQqh2MsC&lpg=PT142&ots=gTytKzg3k-&dq=Der%20Bund%20der%20Kommunisten%2C%20eine%20internationale%20Arbeiterverbindung%2C%20die%20unter%20den%20damaligen%20Verh%C3%A4ltnissen%20selbstredend%20nur%20eine%20geheime&pg=PT142#v=onepage&q=Der%20Bund%20der%20Kommunisten,%20eine%20internationale%20Arbeiterverbindung,%20die%20unter%20den%20damaligen%20Verh%C3%A4ltnissen%20selbstredend%20nur%20eine%20geheime&f=false

Comment: Das Wort _[Unterzeichnete](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Unterzeichnete)_ gehört zu dem alten reflexiven _sich unterzeichnen_ (etwa wie _der Verliebte_ zu _sich verlieben_).

Comment: Are you the same bruce who asked [this question](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/11125/5398) on the same sentence back March?

Answer (score 4):

1) *Dem* refers to *Kongress*.

2) No, your construction is not correct.

3) *eines* refers to *Parteiprogramms*. The words *für die Öffentlichkeit bestimmten,ausführlichen theoretischen und praktischen* give nearer explanations about the program.

The essence of the sentence is:

*Der Bund der Kommunisten beauftragte auf dem Kongress die Unterzeichneten mit der Abfassung eines Parteiprogramms.*

Please be careful with German spelling, when asking questions here. For me as native speaker and maybe also others it is easier to understand what is meant.

Answer (score 3):

ad 2)

> beauftragte auf dem in London im November 1847 abgehaltenen Kongresse

Both “in London” and “im November 1847” refer to “abgehalten”, they say where and when the congress was held, and therefore come before it. The whole phrase “in London im November 1847 abgehaltenen” refers to “Kongresse” (this is an old dative form, btw) and therefore comes before it.

Your example

> ich habe deine gersten an der Uni shoene Tocher gesehen

is gibberish, however

> Ich habe deine gestern an der Uni schöne Tochter gesehen.

is grammatically correct, but has a different meaning from

> Ich habe gestern an der Uni Deine schöne Tochter gesehen.

(Yesterday at uni I saw your beautiful daughter.)

In the former sentence, “gestern“ and “an der Uni” qualify the “schöne” which they precede, so it would roughly translate to

> I saw your daughter, who yesterday at uni was beautiful.